# IE9 HTML Element Resize Bug with Min-Width Child Div

Tags: html, xhtml, internet-explorer-9, css

Consider the following simple example code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style=" height:100%; width:100%; background:yellow; " >
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>IE9 Min-Width Problem</title>
</head>
<body style=" width:100%; height:100%; margin:0; background:green;">
<div style=" position:relative; min-width:300px; max-width:100%; margin:auto; background:red; ">
<div style=" position:relative; min-width:0; max-width:600px; margin:auto; padding:10px; ">
<div style=" position:relative; width:100%; height:600px; background:blue; ">
Page contents go here.
</div><!-- closes content -->
</div><!-- closes inner-wrapper -->
</div><!-- closes outer-wrapper -->
</body>
</html>
```

My website uses code similar to this to achieve a fluid page layout with a min and max width, and it works beautifully in every browser except, surprise surprise, Internet Explorer. For some reason, when you first load the page and re-size it smaller (or zoom in), the HTML element does not re-size, so you immediately get a horizontal scroll bar and the HTML background is visible on the right. However, if you refresh the page the problem goes away entirely and IE acts like every other browser. *It is only on the first initial load of the page that this problem occurs, so if you refresh the page you have to leave and come back to the site.*

Please note that this only seems to occur when the web page is on a server. If you view the html file locally, this bug does not rear its ugly head. That being the case, I've taken the liberty of uploading this code to my testing server for anyone gracious enough to help me figure out what's going on.

View the page at http://pace-testing.net84.net

If **anyone** has **any** information that could be helpful, I would greatly appreciate it. This includes (1) a fix (2) a workaround or (3) a better way of accomplishing my objective. Let me know if you have any questions, as I will be checking this post frequently (I'm pulling my hair out on this one, so I'm anxious to fix it).

*Additional details: I'm running Internet Explorer 9.0.8 on Windows 7 32-bit. The browser is in Internet Explorer 9 Standards Mode due to the XHTML 1.0 Strict Doctype.*

Comment: I don't see that happening in IE9/W7x64 unless I switch on compatibility mode (that broken page icon in the address bar). Maybe you have that switched on acccidentally?

Comment: You're right Andrew, that's a helpful piece of information, thank you. For some reason IE seems to be forcing compatibility mode on this page. When I turn it off it seems to work fine, however when I remove the preference of compat mode for the site and go back to it, it still goes into this mode. Does anyone know how I can work around this? Why does it do this is compat mode? How can I specify for it to never go into compat mode? Sorry, but I have little experience with IE. Ya know, 'cause it's the devil. :)

Comment: @Scopace: Hi there, I'm, having exactly the same issue, and not only with min-width but also with display:table. As you said on tour post it works nicely when i try the page on local, bot when from a server none of these style atribs apply. Did you find a solution for your problem?? Thanx

Answer (score 1):

I don't see that happening in IE9/W7x64 unless I switch on compatibility mode (that broken page icon in the address bar). Maybe you have that switched on acccidentally?

You appear to have a major typo on the second line of the page:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style=" height:100%; width:100%; background:yellow; " >
```

What's the `style` doing in there?

It's a good idea to check your page with [validator.w3.org](http://validator.w3.org/) as it spots things like that. (There are other validators.)

Comment: I know, it doesn't validate, but I just threw this example together quickly and wanted inline styles. I'm accustomed to seperate css files, but the fact of the matter is that it works, even if it doesn't validate. Suffice it to say, my actual website doesn't make this mistake. At any rate, your comment (which belongs as the answer) has told me exactly what I needed to know and for that I can't thank you enough. I believe a little research into IE compatibility mode has given me the solution (the meta tag for compat mode).

Comment: I spoke too soon! I've added <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" /> to the markup, and although it is no longer in compat mode, it still renders incorrectly. What else ya got?

Comment: Well, if it isn't valid HTML you shouldn't expect it to work ;) I'd just stick in a `<style type="text/css">` section.

Comment: @Scopace - You shouldn't be relying on broken markup. Do what Andrew says.

Comment: I'M NOT RELYING ON BROKEN MARKUP, THIS IS AN EXAMPLE THAT BEHAVES EXACTLY THE SAME AS MY SYNTACTICALLY CORRECT WEBSITE. JUST BECAUSE A PIECE OF MARKUP DOESN'T VALIDATE, DOES NOT MEAN IT DOESN'T FUCNTION. I ASSURE YOU THAT STYLE TAG IS FUCNTIONING FINE, EXACTLY AS IT WOULD IF IT WERE SYNTACTICALLY CORRECT, MAKING THESE COMMENTS THAT STATE THE OBVIOUS WHOLLY UNPRODUCTIVE.

Comment: Sorry, haven't had my coffee yet. Anyways, if you haven't noticed, the html element's background is yellow, meaning that style tag is working just fine and thus is not the problem. Give me five minutes and I'll prove it by correcting the markup if absolutely necessary, but let's stick with the problem at hand. I don't care if the example doesn't validate, as it will be deleted from my server by the end of the day.

Comment: 1. Have coffee. 2. Notice that you haven't applied the style to any element in the `<style>` section.

Comment: You need something to apply the style to, e.g. `html { height:100%; width:100%; background:yellow;}`, as in: add `html` and surround the style directives with curly braces. Next coffee? ;)

Comment: Ugh, alright my example demonstrating the browser bug is now perfectly valid and 100% correct. Low and behold... it behaves just like it did before! Can we now turn our attention towards the problem and away from the snippet demonstrating it. How about a solution? A workaround? Another means of attaining my goal? Anything, you know... useful. Or shall I spend a few days making that markup the best possible example of a problem everyone seems completely unwilling to address? If you don't know, just say so, please don't "answer" my post with semantics. It wasn't the damn style tag. Period.

Comment: I can no longer reproduce the problem. I also tried IE8 on Windows XP, just in case. Have you tried running IE9 with no add-ons?

Answer (score 0):

I've solved my problem adding this meta, a litle bit different from yours.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
```

Also, you might want to check this post, although you'll need to change somehow the meta tags to make them XHTML compatible

[Compatibility and Standards View](http://webdesign.about.com/od/internetexplorer/qt/force-compatibility-view-in-ie.htm)

Hope it helps